# Parse specific div from raw text using regex?

Tags: regex

So I'm in a situation that requires parsing raw HTML data as a string, this is unavoidable unfortunately otherwise I wouldn't post this. I only need regex to match the class of a div that has an `img` tag as a child.

So this is the code example that I'm dealing with:

```
<div class="summary">
 <h3>Example</h3>
 <div class="explanation">
  <span>This serves as an example for the site.</span>
 </div>
 <div class="user-details">
  <a href="/users/garret1001">mheathershaw</a><br>
  <img src="res/badge522.png"/>&nbsp;<span class="score">522</span>
 </div>
 <div class="help">
  <a href="/help.html" class="label">Help</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

And the div that I'd like to retrieve the class from is the div that contains the image. The exact capture from this example that I'd like (optimally) is `user-details`. The criteria for capturing it is simply if it has `<img ... />` as a child.

Anyone able to help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this,

```
/<div\b[^>]*\bclass="([^"]*)"[^>]*>(?:(?!<\/div>)[\s\S])*?<img\b[^>]*>(?:(?!<\/div>)[\s\S])*?<\/div>/
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/pS4vO5/1)

Comment: Yes this works just to select the entire div and all its contents, but all I want it to return or capture is the class of this div. Any way to do that?